# Haskell: Remove largest list

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list of lists, and a function that returns the list with the most items:

```
extract ::[Plateau]->Plateau

extract(x:xs) 
  |x==maximumBy(compare `on` length)(x:xs)=x 
  |otherwise = extract(xs)
extract []=[""]
```

Now I need a function to take the same `[Plateau]` and return a new `[Plateau]` that has the previous largest removed:

```
prune::[Plateau]->[Plateau]
prune(x:xs)
  |x < (maximumBy(compare `on` length)(x:xs)=x : prune (xs)
  |x>=maximumBy(compare `on` length)(x:xs)=[]
prune [] = []
```

I also call prune with a `sortBy` as to make sure the largest list is last:

```
(extract . prune) (sortBy(compare `on` length)(plateaus))
```

This starts out to work correctly. my List `plateaus` looks like:

```
plateaus = ["01000"], ["01010", "11010", "10010"] ["00101"], ["01101", "01001"]]
```

here it is sorted:

```
 [["01000"], ["00101"], ["01101", "01001"], ["01010", "11010", "10010"]]
```

Now, my function prune is returning a list of

```
[["01000"], ["00101"]]
```

that tells me, for some reason Haskell thinks

```
["01101", "01001"] >= ["01010", "11010", "10010"]
```

When I can clearly see that 2 >= 3 is not true.

Why is this?

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put in to your questions -- you have clearly explored the space a bit before asking.  You might hang out on irc.freenode.net `#haskell` channel so you can have a conversation as you work.  It might be a smoother experience.

Comment: Thanks! ill give that a try when i get back on this tomorrow.  Now im working on some Java with Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List comparison is lexicographic, not by length. So you get the result you see because "01101" >= "01010", which in turn is for the same reason - the first two characters of the two strings are equal and the third character of the first is greater than the third character of the second.

Comment: So i should change these things to lengths?

Comment: Yeah - though instead of the extract/prune business, why not sort by length, reverse and then just look at the head of the list?

Comment: because it will be possible to have more then 1 of the same length.  And i absolutly need the one that is less length. be it -1 or more in length.  Not sure if i explained that good

Comment: You can use groupBy `on` length to gather up all those of the same length and deal with them together.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this might be a simpler choice, perhaps:

```
prune :: [Plateau] -> [Plateau]
prune s@(w:x:xs) = filter ( /= maxplateau ) s
    where maxplateau = maximumBy (compare `on` length) s
prune _ = []
```

This relies on several nice parts of Haskell.

The first is pattern matching - You used this in your question, and in your previous question - here, I'm taking it a step further, to require a list with at least two elements, `w` and `x`.  This allows the fall-through case to handle both the empty- and single-entry-list cases, which should (based on the code you provided) result in the same thing: an empty list.

The second is to use the `@` symbol, AKA [as patterns](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching#As-patterns).  I showed you this in my answer to your previous question.  While just syntactic sugar, and not required, it serves to make the code much more readable.

The third is currying, sometimes called "partial function application".  In my case, I used what [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) calls [partial application of an infix function using sections](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions) (you should read that whole section - very formative, does a very good job addressing a pillar of the Haskell language (in fact, if you actually like or want to get a good beginner's grasp of Haskell, I would read Learn you a Haskell cover to cover, as it's fantastic)).  Anyhow, that's what I was using with `( /= maxplateau )`; normally, the infix function `/=` takes two parameters of the same type, and returns a `Bool` - by wrapping in parenthesis and providing an expression on one side, I have partially applied it.  This produces a function of one `Plateau` parameter, which is perfect to supply to the filter function on a list of `Plateau`s.

Finally, in my edit, I changed my answer a little to use the `where` keyword.  This I did just to make that partial application a little clearer.  I  would encourage you to read more about `where` in the [where section](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where) of Learn you a Haskell (can you tell I'm biased? :^) )

Comment: And it is completely implemented, with no explanations of its workings or opportunities for the OP to learn more. -1

Comment: A well-deserved down-vote; "what costs little is little esteemed," or so they say.  I have edited my answer, and hopefully it is not quite as disappointing.  I look forward to any further criticism you have, as I'm very interested in giving good answers; doing otherwise wastes the time of both the writer *and* the reader.

Comment: Wow! thank you for that. I feel like I'm going to need some green tea to help my brain digest. I have taken a big chunk out of the "Learn you a Haskell" book, but im far from finished.  This is my first experience with the language, and so far it is un-comparable to anything else i have worked with. Thank you for a great answer, and explanation, however since i dont fully understand it. I will not use it in this current application.  I will read this over and over, and implement it in coming projects.