# Haskell returns how many inputs are larger than their average value

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to haskell, writing a simple code that returns how many inputs are larger than their average value. I got error:

> ERROR file:.\AverageThree.hs:5 - Type error in application
>   *** Expression     : x y z**
>    Term           : x
>    **Type           : Int
>   *** Does not match : a -> b -> c
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> averageThree :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Float
> averageThree x y z = (fromIntegral x+ fromIntegral y+ fromIntegral z)/3
>
> howManyAverageThree ::Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
> howManyAverageThree x y z  = length > averageThree
> ```

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble you're having comes from a few places.

First, you aren't applying either function, `length` or `averageThree` - and hence also not using your arguments to `howManyAverageThree`.

Second, the type of `length` is `[a] -> Int`.  As you don't have a list here, you either have to use a different function, or make a list.

If I understand your desired algorithm correctly, you are going to need to do a few things:

1. Apply `x` `y` and `z` to `averageThree`.
2. Use [the `filter` function](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#maps-and-filters), comparing this computed average with each passed in parameter; this will result in a list.
3. Find the length of the resulting list.

The code I dashed off to do this follows:

```
howManyAverageThree ::Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAverageThree x y z = length $ filter (> avg) the_three
    where avg = averageThree x y z
          the_three = [fromIntegral x,fromIntegral y,fromIntegral z]
```

This takes advantage of a couple of neat features:

1. Currying, sometimes called ["partial function application"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions). That's what I was using with (> avg); normally, the infix function `>` takes two parameters of the same type, and returns a Bool - by wrapping in parenthesis and providing an expression on one side, I have partially applied it, which allows it to be used as a filter function
2. [The `where` keyword](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where). I used this to clean it all up a little and make it more readable.
3. The `filter` function, which I mentioned above.
4. [Function application using `$`](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application).  This operator just changes the function application from left-associative to right-associative.

Comment: Terminology nitpicks: #1 would technically be called a ["section"](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-300003.5), which of course does make use of partial application. "Currying" generally refers to the act of making a function so that it can be partially applied, so the "currying" isn't really done by you; in the case of Haskell all functions are curried by default. You can also use [curry](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:curry) to curry an uncurried 2-argument function.

Comment: @DanBurton - Absolutely.  I originally clipped that bullet from a prior answer of mine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732243/haskell-remove-largest-list/7732781#7732781), but cut the text about sections because it got long winded.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems here:

- `length` doesn't do what you want it to. `length` returns the length of a list, and there are no lists in your `howManyAvergageThree`
- `averageThree` returns a Float. `howManyAverageThree` needs to account for that. Specifically, `>` needs its arguments to be of the same type.
- The call to `averageThree` in the second function needs some arguments.

Here's a working version:

```
howManyAverageThree x y z = length [ i | i <- [x, y, z], fromIntegral i > avg]
        where avg = averageThree x y z
```

Comment: ERROR file:.\AverageThree.hs:4 - Undefined variable "i"

Comment: I think I had the clauses of my list comprehension backwards. Put `i <- [x, y, z]` first (as in the current, edited version) and it works for me.