# Haskell howManyAboveAverage Couldn't Match Type Error

Tags: haskell

I am a Haskell beginner currently working through The Craft of Functional Programming 2nd Edition. One of the exercises in the book asks me to write an averageThree function, which I have did, and then a howManyAboveAverage function using the averageThree function.

I was a bit stuck on how to do this but I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793281/haskell-returns-how-many-inputs-are-larger-than-their-average-value). I used the solution given in my code however I am getting a parse error [FIXED].

Here is my new code:

```
averageThree :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Float
averageThree a b c = fromIntegral (a + b + c) / 3

howManyAverageThree :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAverageThree a b c = length $ filter (> avg) the_three
    where avg = averageThree a b c
          the_three = fromIntegral <$> [a,b,c]
```

EDIT: New Error
Error trace:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( average.hs, interpreted )

average.hs:7:36: Not in scope: `<$>'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I use ghci version 7.6.3 for compilation. Since I'm following a textbook example I need to preserve the function signatures. How can I modify this code such that I no longer get the above error?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your edit, in the future, please don't move the goalposts on questions! If an answer solves your original problem, but exposes a new one, it is better practice to accept an answer to the first one and ask a new question for your new problem.

Comment: Side note: that book looks a little outdated (it says to use Hugs). I would look into a more up to date resource that will give you a better idea of what to do and will have a more linear learning curve. I learned using "Learn you a Haskell", and I've heard good things about "Real World Haskell". They are both free online.

Comment: I also use a futurelearn course but I found the initial learning curve to be too steep. This book was recommended to me by the person running the course as a more gradual intro before tackling futurelearn in more depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Haskell, [indentation does matter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation). You need to match the indentation in your `where` clause:

```
howManyAverageThree :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAverageThree a b c = length $ filter (> avg) the_three
    where avg = averageThree a b c
          the_three = fromIntegral[a b c]
```

EDIT: 
Following your edit to the question, you need to look more closely at the definition of `the_three`:

```
the_three = fromIntegral[a b c]
```

`fromIntegral` has type `:: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`

If you want to `the_three` to be a list of numbers, you need to do a few things. 
First, your list constructions needs `,`'s inside it. Second, you need to map `fromIntegral` over each element of that list.

```
import Control.Applicative((<$>))
....

the_three = fromIntegral <$> [a,b,c]
```

Comment: Okay I copy pasted your response and it gave me a new error, question has been updated with the error trace.

Also I don't understand what was wrong with my indentation, the where was exactly 4 spaces in and the_three was exactly 4 as well. I acknowledge there was obviously something since your solution fixed it I just don't understand.

Comment: @KaiD Mixing tabs and spaces can typically cause issues that make things look like they line up, but aren't actually.

Comment: @KaiD `where` just starts the block; it's the next token that sets the required indentation level for the block. So lining up `the_three` with `where` (as you say you did: both indented four spaces) is incorrect, as you should be lining up `the_three` with `avg` instead (so indent `the_three` by four spaces to come to the beginning of the `where`, plus six more spaces to account for `where␣`).

Comment: I'll be more careful with indenting in the future then, thank you Daniel I didn't know that i'll bear it in my for future coding. Your solution above gave me a different error again, question updated.

Comment: @jkeuhlen This isn't related to tabs, I don't think. None of his edits include code with a tab in it, and his description of his code explicitly refers to spaces.

Comment: @DanielWagner You're definitely right. I just misunderstood what he meant in "exactly 4 spaces".

Comment: @KaiD import Control.Applicative